# Moving .htaccess to apache 000-default.conf

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I am trying to move the content of .htaccess to apache.

This is my .httaccess which works fine.

```
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^contact-me/?$ index.php?page=contact [NC,L]
     RewriteRule ^about-me/?$ index.php?page=about [NC,L]
```

I moved the .htaccess code to 000-default.connf as below:

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.mysite.com

     <Directory /var/www/>

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^contact-me/?$ index.php?page=contact [NC,L]
     RewriteRule ^about-me/?$ index.php?page=about [NC,L]

     </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
```

Which doesn't work, but if I put "Deny from all" or other rules it works fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: are you using apache 2.4?

Comment: yes, I'm using the latest version

Comment: you probably would need to add this `require all granted`, reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: i already have require all granted in apache2.conf

Comment: you would need to explicitly define another rule for virtual host.

Comment: If I put require all granted in vhosts, apache doesn't even starts

Comment: you would need to put the require under the directory for the vhost itself.